# R summarise sum

Tags: r

I want to be able to summarise the following, but I'm not sure how to
So the table is like this

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Name, ~`Number B`, ~total,
    "e",       1,         3233,
    "e",       2,         3222,
    "f",       1,         377,
    "f",       2,         456,
    "t",       1,         3266,
    "e",       1,         44,
    "t",       1,         3266,
    "f",       2,         909
  )
```

So I want to be able to get the totals of number ones per name. There are 2 e's number 1's etc.The columns are Name, Number b and total

Similar table of numbers in the pic. The table didn't come out too well above
[here is a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwW2G.png)

Comment: Also, please take some time to review how to provide a properly formatted [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'Name' and get the `sum` of subset of 'total' based on the logical expression from 'Number B'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>%
   summarise(NumberOne = sum(total[`Number B` == 1]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Name  NumberOne
#* <chr>     <int>
#1 e          3277
#2 f           377
#3 t          6532
```

---

Or with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
collap(sbt(df1, `Number B` == 1, -`Number B`), ~Name, fsum)
#  Name total
#1    e  3277
#2    f   377
#3    t  6532
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(total ~ Name, subset(df1, `Number B` == 1), sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("e", "e", "f", "f", "t", "e", "t", "f"
), `Number B` = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), total = c(3233L, 
3222L, 377L, 456L, 3266L, 44L, 3266L, 909L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Number B has a space in between r and B

Comment: @thewal - If akrun's solution addresses your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark. This will help future users with the same / similar problem you have.

Comment: Perfect, this works for me, thanks. Last night I was using 'Number B' and it didn't work. This morning, fresh eyes I used `Number B` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` approach:

Note: Thank you @Akrun for the data.

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("e", "e", "f", "f", "t", "e", "t", "f"
), `Number B` = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), total = c(3233L, 
3222L, 377L, 456L, 3266L, 44L, 3266L, 909L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))


library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(total_one = sum(total[`Number B` == 1])),
           by = Name][]

#>    Name total_one
#> 1:    e      3277
#> 2:    f       377
#> 3:    t      6532
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Same idea but having the filter out of the summation: `df1[,.(total = sum(total)),.(Name, `Number B`)][`Number B`==1,]`

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(total ~ Name + NumberB,data = df1, FUN = sum)
```

OR

```
aggregate(df1$total, by = list(df1$Name, df1$NumberB), FUN = sum)
```

Both are equivalent